# Is it possible to import custom data into Sonar or Sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube, continuous-integration

I've been wandering the Internet for the past few days without result.

I want to import a csv file that contains some data into sonarQube, and use the platform to generate a nice report.

Is it possible to achieve that ? Or should I develop a plugin that meet my needs (I have a personnal preference for Java)? If so, can you explain the process ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the data you want to import? SonarQube reports on metrics and thresholds so you'd need to be able to define your data in a way that would make sense to SonarQube's Compute Engine.

Comment: My csv files contain a few tables, without any metrics